# Empty SMPTE 2094-40 data

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, android-studio

I have been constantly facing this issue where my console displays Empty SMPTE 2094-40 data and so I'm unable to run the app. Please help

I have tried to update the current version of my Android studio but still the problem persist.

Comment: have you run flutter doctor -v

Comment: Yes but it didn't help it shows issue in 2categories one is vs code is not recognize and the other one is related to network resources

Comment: can you include it? Also what kind of platform and device are you trying to run on?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes sir, currently I'm using Android studio flamingo and am using physical device for running the application